# Why does Scrapy use its own shell and how can I use scrapy in pythons interpreter

Tags: python, scrapy

I was wondering about using other Python packages to help understand how Scrapy works and if needed so build out functionality with my scraper. (Mostly help it navigate links and JS elements with selenium/bs4.)

Maybe I'm over complicating things, but this is how I learn.

On to the question, **why** does scrapy have its own shell and **how** can I use it with Python's interpreter?

Comment: The answers to both of those questions can be found in the same page of Scrapy documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html . There is example of how to create Python classes which you can use in your program, as well as a note why it is useful to have shell.

Comment: scrapy has own shell to make our life easier. You don't have to import modules, you can start with url and it will load it, etc. So you can at once start testing xpath, check elements, etc. And this shell is also python interpreter so you can run python code, import modules like BS4. If you have installed ipython then shell will use it.

Comment: How can you load scrapy shell with iphython? @furas

Comment: scrapy shell is python interpreter with extensions. If you have installed `ipython` then scrapy shell will use it instead of standard python interpreter. BTW: `ipython` is python interpreter with extensions.